# How to filter the listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-filterable

There are many solutions provided to this question, but I am not getting exactly where I am going wrong. I have a custom adapter, and I want to filter it.

My adapter class is as follows.

```
public sendivitesadapter(Context context,ArrayList<Item> items,String[]udis) {
        super(context,0,items);

        this.context= context;
         mCheckedState = new boolean[items.size()];
        this.qrusers =(qrusers) context;
        this.items = items;
        this.udis=uid;
        //mContext = context;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Item getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = convertView;

            final Item i = items.get(position);

            if (i != null) {
                if(i.isSection()){
                    SectionItem si = (SectionItem)i;
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.checkboxlist, null);

                    v.setOnClickListener(null);
                    v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                    v.setLongClickable(false);

                    final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                    sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());

                }else{
                    sendItem ei = (sendItem)i;
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.checkboxlist, null);
                    final TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.contactname);
                    final TextView subtitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.companyname);
                     checkBox=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checboxlist);
                    //checkBox.setTag(position);
                    //items.addAll(uid);


               checkBox.setTag(udis[position]);





               checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    if(isChecked){

                        //  isChecked=true;
                        s=(String)buttonView.getTag();
                        Log.e("IDDDDDDDD", s);

                        userid.add(s);
                        Log.e("Array", userid.toString());
                    }
                    else{

                        s=(String)buttonView.getTag();
                        userid.remove(s);

                    }

                    SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(qrusers.this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();

                    editor.putString("userid", TextUtils.join(",", userid));
                    editor.commit();
                }
            });

                    if (title != null) 
                        title.setText(ei.contactname);
                    if(subtitle != null)
                        subtitle.setText(ei.companyname);

                }
            }
            return v;
        }

         public Filter getFilter() {
                if (mFilter1 == null) {
                    mFilter1 = new ItemsFilter1();
                }
                return mFilter1;

            }

        private class ItemsFilter1 extends Filter{

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                    results.values = items;
                    results.count = items.size();

                }
                else{

                     ArrayList<Item> itemsList1 = new ArrayList<Item>();

                     for (Item i : items){

                         if (i.toString().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                                itemsList1.add(i);
                     }
                     results.values = itemsList1;
                        results.count = itemsList1.size();
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                 if (results.count == 0){

                     notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                 }
                 else{

                     ArrayList<Item> lst1 = (ArrayList<Item>)results.values;
                     ArrayList<Item> itemsList1 = new ArrayList<Item>(lst1);
                     //this.items=mItems;
                    items =itemsList1;              
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }

            }



        }
```

and in my activity I have used this code.

```
 usersearch1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        if (usersearch1.getText().toString().equals("")){
                            sendadapter  = new sendivitesadapter(qrusers.this,items1,uid);

                            listView.setAdapter(sendadapter);



                        }

                        s=usersearch1.getText().toString();
                        Log.e("ALPHABETS", usersearch1.getText().toString());
                        sendadapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                    }
```

There are no errors, but when I type in EditText ,nothing happens. Please let me know I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

add onTextChanged method

```
  if (!usersearch1.getText().toString().equals(""))
  {
    sendadapter.getFilter().filter(s);

   //Must
    sendadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all - why are you setting your adapter inside `TextChangeListener`? Whatever you type inside your EditText it will refresh your `listView` without making any changes to it.

second of all - if you have implemented well your `getFilter()` method inside your `sendadapter`, then the only thing you should do inside `onTextChange` is to reset data of your adapter (get default view of your adapter data) and then execute `sendadapter.getFilter().filter(s)`

so, in your `onCreate` of your activity you should do at least this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.YourSearchActivity);

    //since you haven't show rest of the code, im guessing names of the variables and U elements
    //connect UI elements with varables in code
    EditText usersearch1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usersearch1);       
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview)
    sendadapter = new sendinvitesadapter(yourActivity.this, YourListOfItems, YourStringofUdis);

    /*
    *  REST OF CODE
    */

    //set text listener to your EditText 
    usersearch1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
        {
            // if (count < before) {sendadapter.resetData();}
            //resetData() method might be necessary, if your filtering method won't react on backspace 
            Log.e("ALPHABETS", usersearch1.getText().toString());
            sendadapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
    });


    /*
    *  REST OF CODE
    */

    //set adapter
    listView.setAdapter(sendadapter);
    //enable filtering of your list
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);                            
}
```

Comment: then you should rethink again your entire code. it's not so hard to make a mistake while working with custom adapter... the code i posted is my own code, and it is working for me... sorry i couldn't help :(

Comment: Can you please share your code here..!! SO that I can go through it.